# Need to have Highcharts datalabels set differently to y axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that shows people, a monetary value and a percentage.

I would like to display the percentage as the datalabel instead of the monetary 
value.

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
        bar: {
            dataLabels: 
            {
                allowOverlap:true,
                enabled: true,
                align: 'right',
                overflow:"none",
                formatter: function() { return this.y;},
            }
        }            
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["Mary<br/>$ 4,623,450","John<br>$     1,848,380","Jane<br/>$ 640,170"]
        },
        series: [{
            "data": [
                ["65%",4623450],
                ["26%", 1848380],
                ["9%", 640170]
            ],
            "name": "Session1"
        }]
    });
});
```

So:
Mary would have a datalabel of 65% instead of 4623450,
John would have a datalabel of 26% instead of 1848380,
Jane would have a datalabel of 9% instead of 640170

Is there a way to do that?

[See jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mhluzi/80ykhfav/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

As simple as:

```
formatter: function() { return this.key;},
```

Full code:

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'bar'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
    bar: {
        dataLabels: 
        {
            allowOverlap:true,
            enabled: true,
            align: 'right',
            overflow:"none",
            formatter: function() { return this.y;},
        }
    }            
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ["Mary<br/>$ 4,623,450","John<br>$     1,848,380","Jane<br/>$ 640,170"]
    },
    series: [{
        "data": [
            ["65%",4623450],
            ["26%", 1848380],
            ["9%", 640170]
        ],
        "name": "Session1"
    }]
});
```

});

[Updated jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mhluzi/80ykhfav/4/)